# Midnight Commander multi-rename with numerical values for new file names

Tags: batch-rename, midnight-commander

With <kbd>F6</kbd> we can multi-rename group of selected files in **mc**. I know, for example, how to search and replace using some regexp tokens subset in this menu. But how to proceed if I need rename a group of files by adding a numeric counter to new filename? For example, given the selection:

```
a.sh
b.sh
c.sh
```

I want to rename files to:

```
01.sh
02.sh
03.sh
```

Is there some counter token?

Answer (score 3):

There is no *counter token* to do that. But Midnight-Commander is too powerful to be so easily defeated! Create this new entry in your user menu (`Command > Edit menu file > User` or `~/.config/mc/menu`):

```
x       Rename with 00->99 counter preserving extension
        i=1
        for file in %s; do
            extension=.${file##*.}
            [ "$extension" = ".$file" ] && extension=""
            cnt=$(printf '%%02d' "$i")
            mv -- "$file" "$cnt$extension"
            i=$((i+1))
        done
```

Then select the files to be renamed, bring up the user menu with <kbd>F2</kbd> and choose your new action with <kbd>x</kbd>.

Sample execution:

```
$ ls
a.sh   b.sh   c.sh  'h 10'  'zr.X&*!#@.f90'
```

After selecting all the files and applying the action:

```
$ ls
01.sh  02.sh  03.sh  04  05.f90
```

---

The shell script explained.

```
i=1
# %s expands to all selected files and we loop through each
for file in %s; do 
    
    #This gets the extension of the file by removing everything up to the last dot
    extension=.${file##*.}

    #If the file had no extension, set extension to null
    [ "$extension" = ".$file" ] && extension=""

    #Format the counter appropriatedly, zero padding 1 to 9
    #A double % is needed because MC interprets % especially, as noticed above with %s
    cnt=$(printf '%%02d' "$i")

    #Perform the renaming in a file, preserving extension (if existing)
    mv -- "$file" "$cnt$extension"
    
    i=$((i+1)) #Increment counter
done
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your great job, but will be cool if some **mc** solution works like Multi Rename in **Total Commander** on Windows. I mean when you can have full control with this rename and counter. For example if you need to rename just part of filename with numbers and you can select prefix zeros + start counter value..

Comment: @mature Glad to hear it was helpful! Now, it is not clear to me what you mean with the "For example..." part. If you clarify it, I may be able to help, but if it deviates to much from the original question, then I'd ask you to open a new question.

Comment: Nice solution! Works like a charm! Is there a way to call a popup window to ask for some prefix? To get `"$prefix ($cnt)$extension"`